# xml schema : check if list is ascending

Tags: xsd

I have in an xml element an attribute "period", which is a list of 2 dates.
for ex. period="2020-01-01 2020-03-31"

Is there a way to check with xml schema if this list is ascending (first date smaller or equal as second date)?

my xml-schema code :

```
'''
<xsd:simpleType name="type-list-date">
    <xsd:list itemType="xsd:date"/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="type-period">
    <xsd:restriction base="type-list-date">
        <xsd:length value="2"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
'''
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not. A schema simple type describes a single atomic value, and a List type is just a sequence of unrelated instances of a simple type. It looks as if your list has exactly two members, so it should be possible to write an XPath boolean expression that returns true if your constraint is satisfied.

If I was designing this XML format I would put the two dates into separate attributes/tags with names 'startDate' and 'endDate' (or similar).